# what's the usage of named pipes ? can I connect from management studio using a named pipe?

Tags: sql, sql-server

at the moment I turn on the TCP/IP in sql server network configuration and enable the ip used for connection
after I'm able to connect using management studio

I saw that there is also an option to connect using named pipes, but I could succeed to connect from management studio using the pipe name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote MSDN from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892.aspx

**Named Pipes vs. TCP/IP Sockets**

*In a fast local area network (LAN) environment, Transmission Control Protocol/Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) Sockets and Named Pipes clients are comparable with regard to performance. However, the performance difference between the TCP/IP Sockets and Named Pipes clients becomes apparent with slower networks, such as across wide area networks (WANs) or dial-up networks. This is because of the different ways the interprocess communication (IPC) mechanisms communicate between peers.*

*For named pipes, network communications are typically more interactive. A peer does not send data until another peer asks for it using a read command. A network read typically involves a series of peek named pipes messages before it starts to read the data. These can be very costly in a slow network and cause excessive network traffic, which in turn affects other network clients.*

*It is also important to clarify if you are talking about local pipes or network pipes. If the server application is running locally on the computer that is running an instance of SQL Server, the local Named Pipes protocol is an option. Local named pipes runs in kernel mode and is very fast.*

*For TCP/IP Sockets, data transmissions are more streamlined and have less overhead. Data transmissions can also take advantage of TCP/IP Sockets performance enhancement mechanisms such as windowing, delayed acknowledgements, and so on. This can be very helpful in a slow network. Depending on the type of applications, such performance differences can be significant.*

*TCP/IP Sockets also support a backlog queue. This can provide a limited smoothing effect compared to named pipes that could lead to pipe-busy errors when you are trying to connect to SQL Server.*

*Generally, TCP/IP is preferred in a slow LAN, WAN, or dial-up network, whereas named pipes can be a better choice when network speed is not the issue, as it offers more functionality, ease of use, and configuration options.*

---

**Using with SSMS**

If named pipes is enabled when you install SQL Server, you can use it from SSMS. You may have to use CliConfg.exe to configure to setup a server for Named Pipes.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use named pipes only on the same machine (or on a local subnet).

Reference:

[Named Pipes vs. TCP/IP Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178138(SQL.80).aspx)